# Mounting USB Device in same location

Tags: usb, mount, udev

I am using an USB Device as a replacement for a floppy disk. I am only using one USB device at a time. How can I make Ubuntu to mount ANY USB device into a fixed folder, eg. /media/USERNAME/USB?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**As far as I know this will be impossible**

USB devices are mounted with their name so you need to alter the name of the device.

Test with 2 different pendrives:

Open **disks** from dash.

- 4,1 Gb Cruzer, Renaming to "usbdisk".
- Click the cogwheel in the middle (below the orange volume).

[image]
[image]

- 16.1 Gb, BSix, Renaming to "usbdisk".

[image]

[image]

The Cruzer is now mounted as "usbdisk".

[image]

If you mount the 2nd one it will error out (image created before a reboot but it also shows up after a reboot):

[image]

As you can see in the error notice it knows "usbdisk" should be a Cruzer so I doubt this is possible. The system matches the device name what is uses to mount it with the internal name (ie. the "identify as") it uses to identify the pendrive. So 2 mountpoints with the same name will be impossible.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your try! I guess another method could be to name the mounted devices after the port not the device name / id. So I may find all my devices which I plug into USB Port A in /media/hans/USBA and so on. Following that I could mark one port as "Floppy" in which I could plug in my USB sticks.